# How to display a select list from a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My select list in a form_for is looking strange:

```
<select id="user_user_status" name="user[user_status]">
<option value="#&lt;UserType:0x007fcfb49bfee8&gt;">7</option>
..
..
</select>
```

I have an hash that I created like:

```
UserStatus.all.each do |u|
  USER_STATUS_BY_ID[u.id.to_i] = u
end
```

I then created my select list inside a form_for like:

```
<%= f.select :user_status, USER_STATUS_BY_ID.each {|k,v| [k, v.name]} %>
```

The value.name doesn't seem to be rendering the name, but the entire object it seems?

I was expecting to have the name ouputted...

Comment: `each` returns the collection that you iterated on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
<%= f.collection_select :user_status, UserStatus.all, :id, :name %>
```

Update: If you want to use the hash, it looks like you need a map instead of an each:

```
USER_STATUS_BY_ID.map {|k,v| [k, v.name]}
```

Comment: but I want to use my hash, not the model.